# How do you make a function that subtracts 2 values but will make value "a" not go beneath 0?

Tags: java, subtraction

I want to subtract the Value of food from the value of hunger but hunger is not allowed to ge below 0. How would I achieve that ?
Also I code in Java

```
public void eat(Food food) {
        
        if (this.hunger > 0 && food.getTyp() == "Dogfood") {
            hunger = hunger - food.getVolume();
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Something like `a = a - somevalue; if (a < 0) a = 0;`

Comment: Please note that you are comparing strings with `==`. That will not do what you think it does. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/4125191).

Comment: `hunger = Math.max(0, hunger - good.getVolume());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void eat(Food food) {
    if ("Dogfood".equals(food.getTyp())) {
        hunger = hunger - food.getVolume();
        hunger = hunger < 0 ? 0 : hunger;
    }
}
```

Like this, every time the value of hunger is set to a new value, the new value is calculated. Then, if hunger < 0, it is set to 0.
Also, I changed your equals method according to one of the comments.